# boot time & usb

Tags: boot, usb, touch-screen

In a coming new system we need to have a very short boot time (up to 3 seconds). The system shall also have a USB connected to touch screen.

We are afraid that the USB enumeration might take too much time, and think that it might be better to prepare an SPI connection (and driver) to the touch, and use SPI connectivity and driver instead of USB driver.

**Is it that USB enumeration really takes that long in boot ?**

I have not find much details on boot time of USB enumeration and if it should really be removed for time optimization.